# What is the proper solution to a web server trying to write to a directory?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, users, umask

So, I have a box with a "deploy" user.  This deploy user owns a code repository and wordpress is running on this box...

When wordpress attempts to do something like upload a plugin, it is using the user "www-data" to write to "wp-content/plugins"..  Apparently it is uploading a zipfile, unarchiving, and then removing the zipfile.

I kept running into problems where wordpress was unable to do these things..  Since my entire code repository was set to be the owner and group:  "deploy:deploy", obviously www-data is not able to access this.

So, my first attempt was to add www-data to the deploy group.

```
usermod -a -G deploy www-data
```

Immediately after issuing this command, I found that I could no longer ssh into the box..  Totally confused as to why-- can anyone fill me in on that?  So I ended up doing:

```
chmod -R go-w ~
```

And then could ssh in again...  doing "groups www-data" showed deploy as one of the options, so I thought hooray...  I went and made sure the wp-content and plugin directories all had write access for the group, and they did...  Double horray, it should work perfectly!

However, no...  Failure upon trying to upload a plugin.

After much annoyance, I just went into the apache config and changed the APACHE_RUN_USER & GROUP to "deploy"

Problem solved...  Sort of.  Except the idea of apache running as the main user, I think is awful.

Anyway, so after making this change, uploading a plugin was successful and I saw:

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 deploy deploy 4096 Oct 22 21:28 wp-crm
```

So, the group has no write access--  I thought maybe this is a hint to why this was failing...  But then, the fact that it's writing with deploy, means that's not really a hint...  Because that's just due to how deploy's umask is set to..  I assume...

So... I am just lost as to what the solution is...

Should my wp-content group be www-data instead?

Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: If you use something CGI-based with suexec, then php code can be executed as another user. The reason it is www-data is because the php code is being interpreted by apache itself, via mod_php.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to this would be filesystem ACLs. I'm not sure I agree with the setup (because the directory isn't static, and it's not using some other directory for temp data), but that's another matter.

With filesystem ACLs, you can grant the `www-data` user access to a specific directory, even though the normal permissions dont allow it.

So for example

```
setfacl -R -m user:www-data:rwx wp-content/plugins
setfacl -d -R -m user:www-data:rwx wp-content/plugins
```

The first command grant's `www-data` read+write+execute to `wp-content/plugins` and everything in it (recursively). The second command sets the default permissions so that any new files and folders created in `wp-content/plugins` will have the specified ACL (and thus be read+write+execute by `www-data`).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `usermod -G` *replaces* the user's groups.  You wanted `usermod -G -a`.